# Вернуть таблицу с конца. ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

Все что мне нужно это в этом коде вернуть таблицу в обратном порядке. И метод Reverse тут не помогает. Так как тут не чистый массив а дата с попутными параметрами.

```
 IQueryable<Post> source = db2.Post;
```

Код, где что-то вроде

```
IQueryable<Post> source = db2.Post.Reverse();
```

или

```
var x = db2.Post.Reverse();     
IQueryable<Post> source = x;
```

Не Работает:(

Полюбому нужно все это записать в IQueryable, так как эту нужно в дальнейшем коде.

```
var count = await source.CountAsync();
        var items = await source.Skip((page - 1) * 
  pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Используйте `.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)`

Comment: 1) `Не Работает` - что это означает? 2) `вернуть таблицу в обратном порядке` - что такое обратный порядок? 3) Сортировку надо делать в конце запроса,а не в начале.

Comment: @AK это будет работать, если идентификатор - целое число. И не будет работать, если id - guid

Comment: @tym32167 Мы же договорились считать, что это означает маленького гномика, который высовывается из компьютера, смеется и говорит: "Не работает!".

Comment: @Igor да, это я помню :)

Comment: 1)После этого метода в переменной записано мягко говоря "бардак"  2) что б данные с таблицы записались с конца (от последнего до первого) в переменную IQueryable<Post> source

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Comment: _бардак_ - естественно, ведь данные в БД могут располагаться в произвольном порядке. Чтобы не было бардака, нужна сортировка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
```

В конце запроса.

Если у вас нужно сортировать не по Id, то подставьте своё поле.

Также обратите внимание, что в случае guid сортировка не имеет смысла - там рандомные значения, а не автоинкремент.